# d3.js touch and hold to create a line from one element to another

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, d3.js, touch

I'm trying to create a visualisation using d3.js on android (using apache cordova) where I display some elements (for example circles) on the phone's screen and have the possibility to create links (lines for example) between elements.

How it should work:

1. touch and hold on the start element
2. drag to the second element
3. release

A new link should now be formed between the 2 elements. I can achieve this with relative ease using the mouse events, but I'm having difficulties in achieving the same using touch support.

This is a minimum example to show the problem that I'm facing.

```js
var width = 350,
    height = 600,
    colors = d3.scale.category10();

var nodeData =
    [
        { id: 1, x: 50, y: 50 },
        { id: 2, x: 200, y: 50 },
        { id: 3, x: 125, y: 150 }
    ];

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);


var node = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(nodeData)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

node.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', 30)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .on('touchstart', function (node) {
    })
    .on('touchend', function (node) {
    });

node.append('text')
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.id; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

In this example the **touchend** event is always executed on the same element as **touchstart** and I couldn't find a way to obtain the element on top of which the touch operation has ended.

I just started using d3.js so any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to using hit (collision) detection:

```
 svg.on('touchmove', function() {
   var p = d3.touches(this)[0];

   endNode = undefined;
   cs.each(function(d) {
     var self = d3.select(this), 
         x = d.x - p[0],
         y = d.y - p[1],
         l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
         r = 30;

    if (l < r) {
      endNode = d;
    }
  });
});
```

If the move event "hit" a circle, endNode will be defined.

Then in your touchend event, check that we started and stopped on a circle:

```
svg.on('touchend', function(){
  if (startNode && endNode){
    svg.append("path")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .attr("d", "M" + startNode.x + "," + startNode.y + "L" + endNode.x + "," + endNode.y);
  }
  startNode = undefined;
  endNode = undefined;
});
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var width = 350,
      height = 600;
    //colors = d3.scale.category10();

    var nodeData = [{
      id: 1,
      x: 50,
      y: 50
    }, {
      id: 2,
      x: 200,
      y: 50
    }, {
      id: 3,
      x: 125,
      y: 150
    }];

    var startNode, endNode;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    svg.on('touchmove', function() {
      var p = d3.touches(this)[0];
      
      endNode = undefined;
      cs.each(function(d) {
        var self = d3.select(this), 
          x = d.x - p[0],
          y = d.y - p[1],
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = 30;

        if (l < r) {
          endNode = d;
        }
      });
    });
    svg.on('touchend', function(){
      if (startNode && endNode){
        svg.append("path")
          .style("fill", "none")
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .attr("d", "M" + startNode.x + "," + startNode.y + "L" + endNode.x + "," + endNode.y);
      }
      startNode = undefined;
      endNode = undefined;
      cs.attr("fill", "red");
    })

    var node = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(nodeData)
      .enter()
      .append('g');

    var cs = node.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr('r', 30)
      .attr('fill', 'red')
      .on('touchstart', function(d) {
        startNode = d;
      });

    node.append('text')
      .attr('fill', 'white')
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```